# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined : object having list of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to map data using below json format.
An object having list of objects.

'''{"pki_user_id":1234,"vc_username":null,"vc_password":null,"vc_name":"Muhammad","vc_email":"Muhammad.Bilal@gmail.com","b_isreset":false,"b_timeout":0,"_RoleDto":[{"pki_role_id":30019,"vc_rolename":"SuperUser","vc_roledesc":"Super User","vc_type":null,"i_group":0,"_MenuDto":null},{"pki_role_id":20015,"vc_rolename":"COMADM","vc_roledesc":"Competency Admin","vc_type":null,"i_group":0,"_MenuDto":null},{"pki_role_id":2,"vc_rolename":"IT","vc_roledesc":"IT","vc_type":null,"i_group":0,"_MenuDto":null},{"pki_role_id":3,"vc_rolename":"TAA","vc_roledesc":"Time Attendance Administrator","vc_type":null,"i_group":0,"_MenuDto":null}]}'''

This is how I'm retrieving data:

```
        {props.LoginDto.vc_email}

        {props.LoginDto._RoleDto.map((record,i) => (

          <div key = {i}> {record.pki_role_id}</div>
        ))}

      </div>
```

Every time I'm getting this error.
I'using react redux to receive props data.

Comment: If the array result is coming from an **API** maybe add `null` check as `props.LoginDto._RoleDto && props.LoginDto._RoleDto.map()`.

Comment: Yes, it works {props.LoginDto._RoleDto && props.LoginDto._RoleDto.map((record,i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a null check like this:

```
{props.LoginDto && props.LoginDto.vc_email}

        {props.LoginDto && props.LoginDto._RoleDto && !!props.LoginDto._RoleDto.length && props.LoginDto._RoleDto.map((record,i) => (

          <div key = {i}> {record.pki_role_id}</div>
        ))}

      </div>
```

Comment: {props.LoginDto.vc_email} is working fine. When I try to retrieve list of Roles giving undefined error

Comment: after removing code, when I check console log it shows complete data console.log(props.LoginDto)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(props.LoginDto._RoleDto))

Comment: When I added that piece of code then error comes :TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined and console log object values are undefined. Object
Sidebar.js:227 undefined

Comment: Try adding a null check `...LoginDto && props.LoginDto._RoleDto && ` like this. I have updated the answer

Comment: yes it works {props.LoginDto._RoleDto && props.LoginDto._RoleDto.map((record,i)

Comment: this would be easy and readable, please use optioal chaiing instead writing many &&{!!props?.LoginDto?._RoleDto?.map((record,i) =>

Answer (score 0):

{props.LoginDto && props.LoginDto.vc_email}

```
    {props.LoginDto && props.LoginDto._RoleDto && !!props.LoginDto._RoleDto.length && props.LoginDto._RoleDto.map((record,i) => (

      <div key = {i}> {record.pki_role_id}</div>
    ))}

  </div>
```